# Как запустить консоль на эмуляторе android

Tags: android

Как запустить консоль на эмуляторе android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В самом эмуляторе есть консоль, но она не работоспособная. Для роботы с эмулятором из консоли необходимо открыть стандартную консоль в вашей ОС. Перейти в pathtoandroid_sdkandroid-sdk-windowstools и выполнить команду adb shell. На выходе имеем урезанную версию консоли.